# What permission is needed to use a service account to remote run powershell on a server?

Tags: powershell, user-management, remote, user-permissions

I have a internal webapplication With a list of all the servers in our network. I want to be able to run a few PowerShell commands on the servers to gather usefull information. Invoke-WMIMethod and Invoke-Command. I only need permissions to read from the servers. This Works good on the servers I have local admin on, but it's not an alternative to make a service account that is local admin on all the servers.

So how do I set up the right permissions on the service account used on IIS Application pool to get read only remote access that will make me able to run these PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by taking a look at this MSDN article:

- [Authorize WMI users and set permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551.aspx)

Specifically, there is the following permission you can assign to a user:

- **Execute Methods** - Allows a user to execute WMI class methods.